# How do I make an alert happen daily at 18:15 with bash shell

Tags: shell, bash-scripting, notifications

I'm using bash shell and pushing notifications, but I do not know how to push notifications at a certian time everyday.

`notify-send -u critical Check Database`
that sends a notification but I can not find anything to push notifications at a certian time.

Anybody know?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use [crontab](https://crontab.guru/). This service will remove much of the difficulties with configuring your timing. Simply add this to your own `/etc/cron.d/yourtask`. For example you would want:
`15 18 * * * notify-send -u critical Check Database`

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: type `sudo vim /etc/cron.d/notify` and then paste `15 18 * * * notify-send -u critical Check Database`. Save and exit by: `<Esc>:wq`, then `sudo systemctl cron restart`

Comment: ```sudo sytemctl cron restart``` "Unknown operation cron"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: `sudo systemctl restart cron`